# How to compare againts 24hour time VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

```
...      
SQLText &= " AND P.AppointmentDate >= #" & VarMatchDate & "#"
SQLText &= " AND P.AppointmentTime >= #" & Now & "#"
```

In the MS Access Database I have Times like 15:00, 20:00. When I do the above query its not returning the result I am hoping for. The AppointmentDate work as expected but the time is returning the result I am trying to avoid.

So I would like to show all the future appointment so if there is an appointment at 14:15 and its 14:16 the record at 14:15 should no longer show.

Comment: Try passing the values as parameters and see if that improves your result. Also mention which database type you're using as you might be able to use one of its native methods, like GetDate() in Sql Server. Also mention the data types of the columns you're querying.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer Ahh I see yes AppointmentTime  is set as short text in an acess database and AppointmentDate is set as date/Time.

Comment: Also apply the [formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) in the UI, not in SQL if possible. In .NET `hh` is for 12-hour clock and `HH` is for 24-hour clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this. Using your current code then convert the dates to Universal format like:

```
SQLText &= " AND P.AppointmentDate >= #" & VarMatchDate.ToString(“u”) & "#"
SQLText &= " AND P.AppointmentTime >= #" & Now.ToString(“u”) & "#"
```

But better to use parameters and pass the values into the query object like:

```
SQLText &= " AND P.AppointmentDate >= @AptDate”
SQLText &= " AND P.AppointmentTime >= @AptTime”
Dim command as new SqlCommand(SQLText, connection)
command.Parameters.Add("@AptDate”, SqlDbType.DateTime)
command.Parameters.Add("@AptTime”, SqlDbType.DateTime)
command.Parameters("@AptDate").Value = VarMatchDate
command.Parameters("@AptTime").Value = Now
```